# TypeError using regular expressions for text analysis in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a bit of code that will scan for a every string matching the regular expression "PP+" and tell me how many times it appears.  Here's my code:

```
with open ('testfile.txt') as f:
data = f.read()
data = data.split()

import re


the_sum = 0

prolist = []

for word in data:
    pronoun = re.compile(r'PP+')
    result = pronoun.match(data)
    if word == result:
        the_sum += 1

print the_sum
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/RE_counter.py", line 14, in 
    result = pronoun.match(data)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: That is certainly no the whole error message - Python is very good about telling you what line is the problem - adding that would be a good idea; that being said you do want to escape the `+` as hwnd said (and probably findall too but I can't remember; haven't used much regex in Python)

Comment: For the record, when asking about an error you should tell what is the problematic line as pointed out by python. And they said «the regular expression "PP+"», so it sounds like it's already the actual regex and the `+` shouldn't be escaped

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the whole list in each iteration (that's the *TypeError*), and also weren't checking the match result correctly, since it won't return the word:

```
for word in data:
    pronoun = re.compile(r'PP+')
    result = pronoun.match(word)  # ← you had pronoun.match(data)
    if result is not None:        # ← you had if word == result
        the_sum += 1
```

Comment: Also note you don't need to compile the regular expression in each iteration, you can move `pronoun` out of the loop and reuse it.

Comment: aha, now i see what i was doing wrong, i misinterpreted how the result variable needed to be handled.  thank you so much you've cleared a lot of things up for me ^.^

Answer (score 0):

you can directly get what you by this.

```
with open ('testfile.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print len(re.findall(r"\bPP\+\b",data))
```